# Django App Engine Installation CommandError Issue

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, djangoappengine

I've been following the installation guide on [django app engine doc](http://djangoappengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html).
I had unzip each module and place them in a directory as such[image]
Next, I entered the startproject cmd.

```
    PYTHONPATH=. python django/bin/django-admin.py startproject --name=app.yaml --template=djangoappengine/conf/project_template myapp .
```

But a CommandError will occurred
[image]

I tried editing the startproject line by removing the final ".". This works but a new folder named "myapp" with the path test/myapp/ is created. I don't think that is should be the correct project structure. Shouldn't all the necessary files be in the root folder of test/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised the problems lies with the DS_Store file that is created by Mac. Hence writing the code below will delete those files which will solve the problem.

```
    find . -name '*.DS_Store' -type f -delete
```